Como eu conecto o banco ao HTML
Estou fazendo um site em HTML css e javascript só que eu quero que ele exiba um dado que está cadastrado no banco de dados lembrando que o banco de dados foi feito no Oracle e eu quero que essa conexão seja feita pelo odbc tem como?. Se não tiver como fazer conexão via ODBC como eu faria via JDBC e qual a melhor linguagem de programação eu devo usar.
Urgente!!!!!!!!

Queira antes de usar novamente o site visitar a [help] e ler todos os links sugeridos. Evite ser suspenso ou bloqueado de publicar no site, não duplique as peguntas.

Esta pergunta já foi postada e lá já foram fornecidas as orientações relevantes. Desta forma, o espaço de comentários foi desativado aqui para evitar descentralização de informações (mas continua disponível na postagem original, se restaurada).
